# Connect Visual Studio 2008 (in Windows 7 64 bit OS) with Windows Mobile handheld 6.5.3 device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, smart-device, handhelddevice, intermec

I have two questions below.

1. I am a new developer to create an application for Intermec CK71 device (Windows Mobile handheld 6.5.3 OS) to scan the barcode and capture the data. I studied that I need a synchronization tool to connect VS 2008 to the device. I noticed that ActiveSync 4.5 and Windows Mobile Device Center(WMDC) do not support VS 2008 in win 7 OS. Could you please let me know which tool does support VS 2008 in win 7 OS to sync up the data with device ?
2. As I am a new developer for Intermec CK71 device (Windows Mobile handheld 6.5.3 OS), could you please suggest what are the softwares required to develop, debug, test and deploy the application? I have listed below for VS 2008 in Win 7 environment. Do we require all these or we can remove something?

   - Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=6135)
   - Windows Mobile Device Center(it is available ONLY for windows vista , but not for windows 7)
   - .NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable (www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=65)
   - Windows Mobile 6.5 Developer Tool Kit (www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17284)
   - Windows Mobile 6.1.4 Emulator Images (www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9263)
   - Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Developer Tool Kit (www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5389)

Comment: This is rather a broad question, but did you find the below answer of any help?

Comment: Please rate my answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows Mobile Device Center and Windows 7 are working fine with
   VS2008.
2. Go to intermec-website and download the "IDL" (Intermec Developer Library). You need the "data capture" part.
3. Install a Windows Mobile SDK 6, this should work.
4. View the samples in "IDL" for Barcode-Scanning.
5. Open a new smart device project and add the neccessary intermec-dlls
6. Start programming